# Simplification and rearrangement of a division of two products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am quite embarrassed for even considering posting this, so if the solution is childishly simple, my apologies, but I cannot figure it out.

Suppose I have this function:

$f(a, u, n) = \frac {\prod \limits_{i=1}^n {(a^2 - u[i]^2)^2} }
{ \prod \limits_{i=1}^n {(1 - u[i]^2)^2} } \frac {1} {a^{n - q}}$

where $q=2$ for odd $n$, $0$ otherwise. In whatever place I have to use it, for whatever reason, all the variables are using it as the reciprocal, $x = \frac{1}{f(y, u, n)}$, and its argument, $y$, is also passed as its reciprocal, $y = \frac{1}{a}$. To me, this is very unnecessary, particularly so when I have to make a C++ program for it. $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$ to me, and that's what I wanted to achieve -- transforming the function so that it's already defined as its reciprocal with reciprocal argument.

Next are the steps that I followed. First, reciprocal of the function. For simplicity, just one term of the product:

$\frac{1}{f(a,u,n)}=\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(a^2-u^2)^2}a^{n-q}$

Second, $a = \frac{1}{k}$:

$\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(\frac{1}{k^2}-u^2)^2}k^{q-n}=
\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(1-k^2u^2)^2}k^{4-n+q}$

Is this wrong, so far? It must be because when I test the two functions, I get different results. Here's the code for wxMaxima:

```
f(a, u, n) := prod((a^2 - u[i]^2)^2, i, 1, n/2) / prod((1 - u[i]^2)^2, i, 1, n/2) * (1 / a^(n - 2 * charfun(oddp(n))));
g(k, u, n) := prod((1 - u[i]^2)^2, i, 1, n/2) / prod((1 - k^2 * u[i]^2)^2, i, 1, n/2) * (k^(4 - n + 2 * charfun(oddp(n))));
[_a, _u, _n] : [1.1, [0.9, 0.6], 5]$
float(f(_a, _u, _n)); 1/%; float(g(1/_a, _u, _n)); 1/%;
```

Can someone please help me? For the life of me, I don't see where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "one-term" notation is confusing, since you write terms of the production together with $a^{n-q}$ which is outside of the product.

In particular, the step $\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(\frac{1}{k^2}-u^2)^2}k^{q-n}=
\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(1-k^2u^2)^2}k^{4-n+q}$ is wrong. What you actually mean is $\frac{\prod(1-u^2)^2}{\prod(\frac{1}{k^2}-u^2)^2}k^{q-n}=
\frac{\prod(1-u^2)^2}{\prod(1-k^2u^2)^2k^{-4}}k^{q-n}$ and you notice that the $k^{-4}$ in the denominator appears for EACH term, so you cannot put it outside the product like you (implicitely) did. You should write instead $\frac{\prod(1-u^2)^2}{\prod(1-k^2u^2)^2k^{-4}}k^{q-n} = \frac{\prod(1-u^2)^2}{\prod(1-k^2u^2)^2}k^{4n}k^{q-n} = \frac{\prod(1-u^2)^2}{\prod(1-k^2u^2)^2}k^{q+3n}$

Comment: I feel very blind now. One mistake (mine): the product is until $n/2$, so then $k=k^{2n}k^{q-n}=k^{q+n}$. But now I went to wxMaxima to test it, and the results still differ? Now I'm really confused! If I leave $k^{q-n}$ untouched and add $k^4$ in the product of the numerator, it works, but not outside? What's happening?

Comment: It turns out it's $k^n$, the $q$ cancels. Thank you, I'll mark this as the answer. (can't upvote, though)